# Mentioning a scholarship at the end of an article

Tags: publications, masters

So I finished my first degree and immediatly hoped onto my next (Master's). The issue was that when my supervisor asked me to write the article that contained my diploma thesis I was not able to manage it before I changed universities.

In my new school, I actually managed to obtain a scholarship from a company and I am still writing the article. So my question is, in the scholarship contract that I signed it says that I should mention the scholarship in every paper I ever write. Of course one could say that the work has all been done while I was at my first university.
With that being true, I have grown a lot in my Master's programm and changed because of that. So I  deem it appropriate to refer to that scholarship since my Master's really helped me mature  and change my way of writing and seeing things.

Is it considered appropriate by scientific standards to include the scholarship at the end of the article?

Edit: I forgot to mention that my supervisor is ok with my including it since I seem to have a valid reason. I don't know if others would view it that way.

Comment: If I  correctly understand the situation, the scholarship did not support the research for your diploma thesis but did support writing it up as an article. In a similar situation, I've used an acknowlegement of the form "Much of this paper was written while the author was a visiting scientist at ...."

Comment: so it did not exactly supported in a direct way, but I think I benefitied by the scholarship in the end so I consider it proper to refer to it. Thank you for the suggestion, I will implement something similar!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do scholarship rules really about every paper you write, ever?  This seems absurd, as it could apply to a paper you write thirty years in the future.  Perhaps you can clarify with what the rule actually states?

Comment: they mention for as long as I am under the scholarship whatever i public, i should mention them, at first I wasnt gonna include them, but my master did help and now  my conscience says me to do it, of course stating clearly what their contribution was

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think that their request to mention them in every paper you ever write was inappropriate. I would eventually ignore it unless I had an actual contractual obligation.

But in the short term it is fine to mention them, though whether you say they actually enabled the work or not depends on whether that would be true or not.

I hope they haven't given you a specific formulation. But "I want to thank X for a scholarship that helped fund my early education." is probably honest and without issue.

Comment: Yeah , I was planning to focus on the fact that they funded my Master Studies without mentioning their involvment on the paper  because they didnt. I dont  know exactly what's the correct way and my professor was ok with me mentioning them because from my country the company is really strong in my field and it would only benefit us in a way. I think also that what i signed is  quite uncertain and I could simply ignore because the publication is reffereing to my work before the scholarship and not with my current institution. However as I am planning to affiliate myself with both institutions

Comment: and I am working through it during my stidies that I am also being paid- I find more proper to mention them, reffering to their actual role. I dont think anybody will think that they funded the project since my professor urged me to thank a specific national grant for the project. So i think the liines are pretty much drawn

Comment: I also want to add that I would ahve preffered not to add them but I might too honest of a person and want to write things as they are and not  try to be sneaky. I guess it also is up to the other participating professor and if he agrees.